# getting user input to form linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list from user input but it's not printing anything when i try to print it. Not even the head. Also note, it is intentionally backwards.

Here is my function for getting user input, it returns the list. I know it is wrong but i've spent hours on it and can't get it to work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <ios>

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *next;
}

Node* getInput() {
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tmp;
    while (true) {  
        int x;
        if (!(cin >> x)) {
            break;
        } else if ( head == nullptr) {
            head = new Node{x, nullptr);
        } else {
            tmp = new Node{x , nullptr};
            tmp->next = head;
            head = head->next;
        }   
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    cout << getInput()->value;
}
```

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what `head = head->next;` is for.

Comment: head is assigned to the next link so on the next iteration a new node may be constructed

Comment: `head = head->next;` -- Now do a magic trick and try and remove all of the nodes you created, starting from the original head node.  This is not how you put together a linked list -- it is a little more involved than two lines of code.

Comment: *I know it is wrong but i've spent hours on it and can't get it to work...* -- Did you draw this on paper first, with boxes denoting the nodes and lines denoting the links, before writing any code?  If you did, it wouldn't take hours since you have to mimic exactly what you drew on paper.

Comment: i edited the post. The initial code was just one of many sets i have tried. The new code gives only the first value and not the rest.

Comment: @bg9848 - So you want to print all the `Node`s? Right now you're `return`ing the tail and throwing away (via memory leaks) all the `Node`s that preceed it.

Comment: ok i understand. I tried fixing it but the issue remains. I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of good solutions up, but because the request was for a backward list, this can be really, really simple.

```
Node* getInput()
{
    Node* head = nullptr;
    int x;
    while (std::cin >> x) // keep going until we can't get a good x.
    {
        head = new Node{x, head}; // point node at current head, assign new head
        // head always points at the beginning of list because items are 
        // always inserted at the start of the list.
    }
    return head;
}
```

So to prove this list prints backward, here's a simple tester

```
int main()
{
    Node* cur = getInput();
    while (cur)
    {
        std::cout << cur->value << '\n';
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of get input() is not the actual head/start of the list. Head will always point to null the moment you insert any node. Head value can be stored in a temporary pointer during first insert and return temporary pointer instead of head.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to print the linked list in reverse order, here's a working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <ios>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *next;

    Node(int val, Node *nextPtr) {
        value = val;
        next = nextPtr;
    }
};

Node *getInput() {
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tmp;

    while (true) {
        int x;
        if (!(cin >> x)) {
            break;
        } else if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new Node(x, nullptr);
        } else {
            tmp = new Node(x, nullptr);
            tmp->next = head;
            head = tmp;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

int main() {
    Node *head = getInput();
    Node *tmp;
    while (head != nullptr) {
        cout << head->value << ", ";
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`head = head->next;` is the problem.  You're allocating a `Node` correctly, but you immediately leak that `Node` and `head` is pointing to `nullptr`.

The simplest solution is to keep `head` pointed at the most recent `Node`.  You'll need a special case for the first insertion since `head` will be uninitialized (fix that by the way), but that way you're always pointing at the most recent `Node`.

If you have trouble, draw your `Node`s out on paper with arrows.  Watch how the arrows change at each insertion, and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Since the asker wants a backward list, they don't need the tail. They can keep inserting in front of `head`.

Comment: @user4581301 - Good catch, thanks. I read that, but started going into a standard linked list implementation by default.